# multiple themes not working in vuetify3 and vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to create 3 themes for my app consisting of different properties for buttons, app-bars, toolbars, etc. I want to implement these themes globally in vue3. I have done something like this in my `vuetify.js` file.

```
// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
// Vuetify
import { createVuetify, ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'

const allthemes = {
  komodo: {
    primary: '#4CAF50', // Green for Komodo
    secondary: '#424242',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    button: {
      primary: '#4CAF50', // Green for Komodo
      secondary: '#424242',
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
    appbar: {
      primary: '#4CAF50', // Green for Komodo
      secondary: '#424242',
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
    toolbar: {
      primary: '#4CAF50', // Green for Komodo
      secondary: '#424242',
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
  },
  verus: {
    primary: '#1976D2', // Blue for Verus
    secondary: '#424242',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    button: {
      primary: '#1976D2', // Blue for Verus
      secondary: '#424242',
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
    appbar: {
      primary: '#1976D2', // Blue for Verus
      secondary: '#424242',
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
    toolbar: {
      primary: '#1976D2', // Blue for Verus
      secondary: '#424242',
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
  },
  zcash: {
    primary: '#FFD700', // Golden for Zcash
    secondary: '#FFFFFF', // White
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    button: {
      primary: '#FFD700', // Golden for Zcash
      secondary: '#FFFFFF', // White
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
    appbar: {
      primary: '#FFD700', // Golden for Zcash
      secondary: '#FFFFFF', // White
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
    toolbar: {
      primary: '#FFD700', // Golden for Zcash
      secondary: '#FFFFFF', // White
      accent: '#82B1FF',
    },
  },
};

export default createVuetify(
  {
  theme: 
  {
    defaultTheme: 'allthemes.komodo',
    themes:{
      allthemes,
    },
  },
}
)
```

The following is my `main.js`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { loadFonts } from './plugins/webfontloader'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
import {ref} from 'vue'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  theme,
})

loadFonts()
createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(vuetify)
  .use(theme)
  .mount('#app')
```

The following does not work. How am I supposed to export all these themes and simply change the variable to implement the theme accordingly.

Comment: `vuetify.js` is not used in `main.js`, you can refer to this [project](https://github.com/kingyue737/vitify-next) to start.

Comment: done that get something like this `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vuetify.js?v=36f7a797' does not provide an export named 'ThemeDefinition' (at vuetify.js:5:25)`

Comment: You can remove `ThemeDefinition` because its a `type` used for `Typescript`. Besides, check `vuetify` version is latest.